# consistency of sqlite file in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database in Android. There is a thread that works with 
the db. From another thread, I'd like to copy the sql file to a different location. I do not know whether the db is closed at the moment, or maybe there is a transaction going on at precisely the same moment. Can I assume that the copy of a file will always be a valid sqlite database?

Since the transactions in sqlite are atomic, this looks reasonable but I'd like to be sure.

The db is opened using `DatabaseHelper` and data is inserted time to time with `SQLiteDatabase.insert`. Some times the db is closed and then reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database transactions are atomic, but copying a file is, by itself, not a database transaction.

To ensure that no other `SQLiteDatabase` object can access the database file, execute [BEGIN EXCLUSIVE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) first.
As long as you do not change the database inside this transaction, the database file is in a consistent state.

Comment: ok, get it. It looks like the Android way of doing "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE" is to call `beginTransaction()` on an `SQLiteDatabase`. However, this function is void and can not fail. What will it do if the other, writing thread, has its own lock and is writing at the moment?

Comment: It will wait, or throw an exception.